# Why not show the people who reopened?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reopening-questions

Why does SE show the users who help put your question on hold but does not show the users who helped reopen your question?

This seems off to me not to give the reopeners equal credit. I would rather know who those users are.

Comment: Muze, why do I see a new account for you?  What happened to the old one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, that information is readily available.

Just because it was reasonably easy to find an example among them, I'm going to use one of your own questions as an example: [Could mirrors be put in space to see ourselves in the past?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/124190/29)

Looking at [the revision history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/124190/revisions) for that question, you'll see that between revision 5 and 6, the question was closed as a duplicate by L.Dutch, and then after revision 12 (which is still current) about 44 hours later, it was reopened by yourself and four others, complete with usernames of and links to the profiles of the users involved.

The revision history is readily accessible for any post that has been edited at least once other than the initial edit grace period (which is (currently) five minutes from when it was originally posted; exceptions may apply). Just click the "edited" link below the post.

For questions that haven't been edited, you can access the revision history by replacing `/questions/nnnn/whatever-the-title-is` in the URL with `/posts/nnnn/revisions`, where in both cases `nnnn` is the question's post ID.

In neither case are any special privileges required.

Comment: I learned something today. I didn't notice this. Where would I suggest that this list would replace the other in front?

Comment: @Muze I fail to see what would be the value of that, but if you want to propose it as a feature, since it would be a network-wide change, it should be proposed on [meta.se].